# Do supplies matter between Banner Saga volumes?

Tags: the-banner-saga, the-banner-saga-2

I'm at the end of a replay of the first Banner Saga game. I came out in a far better position than previous play throughs and I have an opportunity to buy a bunch more supplies. This is the first time I've felt like I might be over-buying.

So my question is, do supplies carry between the Banner Saga and Banner Saga 2? Or is this like a certain earlier village stay were you your situation after a chapter jump is just wildly different?

The deets:

- I finished the game after spending some renown on promotions for the final battle; I have 25 renown left.
- I have 522 supplies, enough for 51 days
- The caravan is actually on the small side, with 290 varl, 94 fighters and 433 clansmen. (At least it feels small compared to the earlier Varl war caravan; I don't remember the basis of comparison from my other play throughs.)
- Boersgard market had over 200 supplies for sale; I bought none of them even though I could have bought all of them.

Do I get any benefit from having supplies at the end of the first Banner Saga? Should I just use renown to promote people now? Does renown carry over to the next game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I played the Banner Saga 2 but from what I can remember, everything you mentioned carries over but there is a cap for supplies, the max supplies is 500.

Low level characters will be auto-leveled but the auto-level stats are terrible so I'd advise you to level them up now and max out any stats you feel are important (Break?).

Otherwise, if you don't level them up, since the characters get auto-leveled, you can save the renown from BS1 and use it in BS2 but as I said above, the leveling templates are terrible so you can test it out for yourself.

Also promotions cost less universally, items top out at 20 renown for a level 10 item instead of 25 for a level 5. So save all the renown you can. Clansmen are also useful in BS2 instead of a drag on your resources, carrying them over is good.

Comment: I imported my save into BS2 and played through the first bit. The clansmen, fighters and varl numbers stayed the same, but I had gained 42 renown and lost 21 days of supplies, falling well below 500. I suppose the game counted the days between the games and deducted the supplies.